# How to fix 0x80070002 - The system cannot find the file specified.error?

Tags: windows

I am looking at my ProfileList

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

This shows
[image]

Should I delete the first default(value not set)?

Comment: Some background information would be useful. And you have 2 questions, 1 in the title and 1 in the body.

Comment: @spikey_richie Which info,I will provide them?

Comment: What you're trying to fix, how you landed on a registry key would be a good start...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, please edit your question, instead of submitting a comment

Comment: What you have shown is just the "headers" for that section. The Profile values are farther down - one for each user. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting it will not help, as it is not there.

The "Default" entry is always present, whether a value is assigned or not.
That's what "value not set" means - there is no value.